# Configuring Admin in rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

i have successfully setup rails admin on my application- the problem is that anybody can now access the /admin ..I am using devise, how can I set the admin user and force them to login?

I am not sure how this can be accomplished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a boolean attribute to users table and make it true for admin and then you can use cancan gem https://github.com/ryanb/cancan.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with your answer?

Comment: just add a boolean field like is_admin to users table and make this field true for admin user and then handle routing on sessions_controller create action. you can use seed file or rail console to update field to true.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan.  Tweak permissions appropriately.

ability.rb

```
user ||= User.new # guest user

if user.roles.include? :admin
  can :manage, :all
elsif user.roles.include? :editor
  can :access, :rails_admin   # grant access to rails_admin
  can :dashboard              # grant access to the dashboard
  can :index,       :all
  can :read,        :all
  can :export,      :all
  can :show_in_app, :all
  can :create,      []
  can :update,      []
  can :destroy,     []
  ...
```

app_controller.rb

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  redirect_to main_app.root_path, alert: exception.message
end
```